# How to import ASCII coordinates to TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, import

I have a long file of Brazil coordinates like:

```
(-3.43,-0.56) -- (-3.44,-0.56) -- (-3.44,-0.55) -- (-3.50,-0.55) -- (-3.52,-0.55) ...
```

and I want to import then into a `tikzpicture` environment to use with the  `\draw` command. Some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw 'myfile'
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about using a shell script to transform the source file into TikZ code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the content of a file in an expandable way using TeX's `\input`, which however is renamed to `\@@input` by LaTeX in order to provide a higher level `\input`. The `\draw` command (actually `\path`) of TikZ will expand the following tokens first before looking for the coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \makeatletter
    \draw\@@input coordfile ;
    \makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I assume the coordinates are in `coordfile.tex` or `coordfile` (no extension). You should add a trailing space after the filename and avoid filenames with special, i.e. non-English characters and of course spaces.

---

If you need this more than once you should declare a different name for `\@@input` in the preamble and use this in the body instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\let\expinput\@@input
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw\expinput coordfile ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or, more LaTeX'ish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\expinput[1]{\@@input #1 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw\expinput{coordfile};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can read from files in TeX. Presume you have a file `foo` with content `(0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2)` Then you can read that line and pass it to a draw command as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \newread\bar
  \openin\bar=foo
  \read\bar to\res
  \tikz\draw\res;
\end{document}
```

And that will draw the corresponding lines. If you have multiple lines in a file then `\read\bar to \res` a second time will read the second line from the file. After you are done with it, you should `\closein\bar`. There is also an `\ifeof` which you can use to loop over the file until it contains no more lines.

To go through the entire file, you can simply write a macro that loops as long as there are things to read. For this simple setup to work, the first command in the loop has to be the read of the file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\myloop#1#2#3\repeat{\def\filenm{#2}\def\body{#1#2#3}\iterate}
\def\iterate{\body\ifeof\filenm\let\next\relax\else\let\next\iterate\fi\next}
\begin{document}
\newread\bar
\openin\bar=foo
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myloop\read\bar to\res\draw\res;\repeat
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will add every line of the file to the same `tikzpicture`.

Comment: If there are multiple lines, the lines will _not_ share the same coordinates as each is draw in its own `\tikzpicture`.

Comment: This can be simplified by using the plainTeX version of `\input` which is fully expandable. See my answer. Of course then all lines will be plotted at once.

Comment: If the OP uses this exact method for multiple lines as well, then no. He can of course do the reads inside of a single `tikzpicture` environment depending on the results he wants. I'll add an example where it reads the entire file.