# Problems with pgfplots, loops inside tikzpicture and reading from files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was trying to implement this method ([How to import ASCII coordinates to TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51270/how-to-import-ascii-coordinates-to-tikz)) to import coordinates and draw them, but I am having this problem

```
Undefined control sequence \end{tikzpicture}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \end{tikzpicture}
Extra \endgroup \end{tikzpicture}
Extra \endgroup \end{tikzpicture}
Too many }'s \end{tikzpicture}
Extra \endgroup \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{document} ended by \end{tikzpicture}. \end{tikzpicture}
Extra \endgroup \end{tikzpicture}
Too many }'s \end{tikzpicture}
Extra \fi \end{tikzpicture}
```

My code is simply

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
%Defining loops for tikz
\def\myloop#1#2#3\repeat{\def\filenm{#2}\def\body{#1#2#3}\iterate}

\def\iterate{\body\ifeof\filenm\let\next\relax\else\let\next\iterate\fi\next}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\newread\bar
\openin\bar=borrar.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \myloop\read\bar to\res\shade[ball color=blue]\res;\repeat
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works whenever I do not include the package `pgfplots`, but I need this package for some plots. Is there any other way to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

sorry I forgot to include this. File borrar.tex is just the coordinates for two lines

```
(0.000000,0.000000) -- (0.000000,2.000000) 
(0.000000,0.000000) -- (2.000000,2.000000)
```

Error in the logfile

```
\bar=\read2
! Undefined control sequence.
\endtikzpicture ...r@layerlist@globally \endscope 
                                              \let \pgf@baseline =\pgf@s...
l.17 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of the shortened error messages, please report what's in the log file, which is usually more informative. For instance the first error message is about `\endscope`. Another thing: we don't have `borrar.tex` and can't guess its contents.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Should I include the entire log file? It is pretty long.

Comment: No, that should be sufficient.

Comment: If you want to read the coordinates line by line from the file you need to use `\readline` instead of `\read`.

Comment: The recommended practice is to copy the file into a macro OUTSIDE the pgfplots environment.  \edef\mydata{\input{borrar.tex}}

Comment: @balborian, did one of the tricks from Martin or John help you or do you need further assistance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because with PGFPlots v1.14 the given example compiles without any error message (when not using the external library, which wasn't explicitly mentioned in the question).