# Is there an alternative package for loading the CSV, while still using pgfplotstables/pfgplots to display it?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv

There are several of issues with the CSV parser that is included in PGFPlots.
This isn't surprising, [writing a CSV parser is well-known to be unexpectedly difficult](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble).
A big one for me being that [it doesn't handle quoting correctly.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281794/5834)

I know there are several other packages for loading CSVs,
though I've never used them.

I have grown to like using pgfplots and pgfplotstables to handle the actual display of my tables and plots.

So I am wondering if I can use some other command from another package,
to replace it for the

```
\pgfplotstableread{inputdata.txt}\mydata;`
```

part of my document,
while still using

```
\addplot [mark=*] table [x expr=..., y expr=... ] {\mydata};
```

for displaying it.

I see in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276878/5834) there is a "format" that PGFplots uses internally, so it seems possibly to data-mung anything into that format, in theory.

---

For purposes of demonstrating a package that can be used,
which does handle CSVs correctly.
The following data could be used:

```
age, Name, Country
37,"Natalie Portman","Israel/USA"
46,"Dwayne ""The Rock"" Johnson", USA
1,"Line
breakerson", Linebreakville
```

Full working example and details on why that is infact a legal CSV can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/oxinabox/d8074781c78ed308e1948df42a7c83d1).

Comment: You can take a look on https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that gives a csv file that pgfplots does not handle correctly?

Comment: @Andrew that isn't really the question. I worry that would distract from the question of, "Can I use PGFPlots, while using another package to do that loading.".
But I can do so and will make one up, though I'm not sure I should add it.

Comment: I can believe that such a data set might distract from the point of the question. If that's the case it would still be good i you can add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that people could use for proof-of-concept.

Comment: @Andrew perhaps. Here is a MWE https://gist.github.com/oxinabox/d8074781c78ed308e1948df42a7c83d1
(Well a little more since it has an explanation of what is going wrong).